# Template based letters generation programs

Tags: excel, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge, vba

Is there any free tool to generate pdf documents from excel data

I found some with price (http://xlvba.net/excel_to_word_automation.html) for it but not  free one, can you help ?

Regards,
Ragavendra

Answer (score 0):

The following code will export your chosen Sheet as PDF:

```
FPath = C:\Users\HomeUser\Desktop"
'set path
FName = "NewFilename.pdf"
'set filename

'EXPORT AS PDF
FName = FPath & "\" & FName
Sheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=FName, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False
```